# WebGL enabling gl.BLEND causes fainted visuals

Tags: canvas, webgl, mask, alpha

We have been using WebGL with alpha layered video and images in our WebGL video canvas.

When we enable the following flags :

```
   gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
   gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
   gl.enable(gl.SAMPLE_COVERAGE);
```

And we are getting this output :

[image]

When I don't use those flags, I can see the output as below :

[image]

But in this case alpha channel is not working, and black background with flame video is visible.

Why does enabling alpha causes the masked images to have a fainted color ?
Should I enable any of the flags to achieve a non fainted output ?

```
gl.enable(gl.SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE); // Enable alpha
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE);
gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE);
gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look step for step, where the fainting may come from.

**(1)** According to the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/enable) `gl.enable(gl.BLEND);` activates blending of the computed fragment color values. The actually applied math is defined via [WebGLRenderingContext.blendFunc(sfactor, dfactor)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/blendFunc). In your case currently the default paramaters are applied, so de facto `gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ZERO)`. With that and the given formula you get:

```
color(RGBA) = sourceColor * sfactor + destinationColor * dfactor
            = sourceColor * (1,1,1,1) + destinationColor * (0,0,0,0)
            = sourceColor
```

So per default, the source color is preserved and the destination color ignored, drawing the source above the destination (in this fragment). This way, basically with paper and pencil, you can figure out which of the 15 blending functions suit your purpose. However, for now *that* does *not* explain the fainting.

**(2)** `gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);` has nothing I'm aware of to do with blending.

**(3)** For `gl.enable(gl.SAMPLE_COVERAGE);` read about [Multisampling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Multisampling) in general and [Sample Coverage](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Multisampling#Coverage) in special, and on [gl.sampleCoverage(value, invert)](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glSampleCoverage.xhtml). And that's where the fainting happens, as per default `value` is 1.0 (and `invert` is false) and such fully involving the respective sample color in this fragment.

The question is, whether you actually need Blending ***and*** Sample Coverage. If not, than kick out the -- for this purpose -- more costly and less flexible Sample Coverage and use only Blending for, well, blending. And do the fine tuning for whatever by selecting the proper blending functions.