# WebGL enabling gl.BLEND causes fainted visuals (alpha)

Tags: canvas, webgl, mask, alpha

We have been using WebGL with alpha layered video and images in our WebGL video canvas.

When we enable the following flags :

```
   gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
   gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
   gl.enable(gl.SAMPLE_COVERAGE);
```

And we are getting this output :

When I don't use those flags, I can see the output as below :But in this case alpha channel is not working, and black background with flame video is visible.

Why does enabling alpha causes the masked images to have a fainted color ? Should I enable any of the flags to achieve a non fainted output ?

```
gl.enable(gl.SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE); // Enable alpha
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE);
gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE);
gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
```

Comment: Isn't that *exactly* the question of an another user? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75345107/webgl-enabling-gl-blend-causes-fainted-visuals

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebGL enabling gl.BLEND causes fainted visuals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75345107/webgl-enabling-gl-blend-causes-fainted-visuals)